# How is the Uber/Cabify launch going in Mendoza?

Tags: argentina, uber

Uber and Cabify, [to much fanfare](https://www.wilsoncenter.org/article/uber-the-message-mendoza)  have (*very* -- October 10, 2018, according to [this article](https://www.infobae.com/economia/2018/10/10/uber-ya-puede-funcionar-legalmente-en-mendoza/)) recently launched in Mendoza.

I'll be visiting next month and am curious about the option of relying on Uber to hop among wineries instead of bothering with other modes of transport.

The above articles strike me as essentially press releases; can anyone that's visited very recently offer any empirical advice regarding:

- Availability/wait times -- will I actually be able to find drivers? Throughout the day? In the south (Lujan de Cuyo/Valle de Uco)?
- Prices and competitiveness -- how are the fares, and how are they relative to private hire/taxi/each other?

Answer (score 2):

Following up with my experience:

I did not get allocated (or see, even) any Uber or Cabify in my 4 night stay in Mendoza -- not at the airport, not in Mendoza city, not in the wineries area. A friend reported getting allocated once from in town.

In the end, I relied mainly on remises ordered via WhatsApp (e.g. Mendoza Remiss offers this).

Note well -- this was in mid-late December 2018.